# How to use OAuth for Google API in Outlook 356 Addin Development

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, office365, outlook-addin

I have created a Add-in/Plugin for Office Outlook 365 online. In this Add-in I'm accessing Google drive data, but before accessing any data I must first authenticate the user for his google account.I have installed this Add-in in my Outlook Account. But when ever I try to authenticate google account it throws me an error in the console window of the browser and open two blank browser tabs. The error in the console is "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?proxy=oauth2relay#****immedi…nt.com&include_granted_scopes=true&hl=en&from_login=1&as=-1***2' from frame with URL 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3939#rpctoken=58***666&forcesecure=1'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors."
I have also tried to add the google domain in the appDomain section in the Menifest file of the Addin i.e

```
<AppDomains>   
     <AppDomain>https://accounts.google.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

I'm still facing the same problem.

Following is my Javascript code for Authentication and accessing drive.

```
 function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
    gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': onPickerApiLoad });
}

function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
}

function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
    }
}

// Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        //var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        //view.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
            //addView(view).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            //setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var id = doc.id;
        //getDownloadUrl(id);
    }
    /* var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;*/
}
```

Any help on this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a situation where you may be violating same-origin policy limitations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp123589.aspx